# Could not resolve placeholder 'test.name' in value "${test.name}" in multi-module maven project - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have started with just a simple Spring Boot starter project.

I renamed `application.properties` to `application.yml`

In **application.yml** file, I added just simple code:

```
test:
  name: myAppName
```

I created a controller and added this piece of test code:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Value("${test.name}")
     private String name;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Called it from Postman and it all worked good.

Then I added module named `integration` that is consisted of two more modules `user-service` and `communication-service`

And after when I would run the application I would get this error:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'test.name' in value "${test.name}"
```

Parent `POM` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <modules>
        <module>integration</module>
        <module>integration/user-service</module>
        <module>integration/communication-service</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.w</groupId>
    <artifactId>registration-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>registration-service</name>
    
    <description>Registration service</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.w</groupId>
            <artifactId>user-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.w</groupId>
            <artifactId>communication-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.13</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`Integration` module `POM` that is consistent of two more modules looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>registration-service</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.w</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>integration</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

And `user-service` module `POM` that is inside of `integration` module looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>registration-service</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.wevolv</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>user-service</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.w</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

I am not sure what am I missing here and why I cant read application.yml file any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent pom is of `pom` type and doesn't handle resources under `src/main/resources` by the maven resources plugin in `process-resources` stage.

You should move `src/main/resources/application.yml` from the project root directory into either `integration/user-service/src/main/resources` or `integration/communication-service/src/main/resources`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes this was solution. I moved it to newly created module called `rest`and from there I added other modules as dependencies and it worked great! Thank you!